# Ошибка при использованим команды с аргументом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясняю:
Создаю свой клиент консоли(если так можно сказать), хочу добавить собственную команду для использования. При использовании самой команды: она реагирует и выдаёт ошибку, что аргумент не указан. Но когда пишу команду с аргументом, он её не распознаёт. [image: Скриншот использования]

Прошу, можете пожалуйста подать идею, как это реализовать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можна использовать sys.argv вот так:

```
import sys
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
   print(sys.argv[i])
```

вивод:

```
PS C:\Users\user0\Desktop> python main.py  1 1 2  3
main.py
1
1
2
3
```

а в вашем случае:

```
import sys
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
   if (i == "h"):
      ...
   elif (i == "m"):
      ...
   else:
      print("Argument Invalid.")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за совет =D